# Replace contents of regexp_matches

Tags: regex, postgresql

I've got a regular expression that looks for certain types of numbers in a text string.

```
select regexp_matches
('+(+number: 921163 +number:(814541)) +(number: 770593 number: 772526 number: 771130) +numberer:9088054599082069', ' [0-9]\{6\} |[(][0-9]\{6\}[)]|:[0-9]{6} | [0-9]{6}', 'g');
```

That query successfully returns the numbers I'm interested in, albeit with some extra characters:

```
{" 921163 "}
{(814541)}
{" 770593 "}
{" 772526 "}
{" 771130"}
```

I'd like to then strip out all of the extra, non-numeric characters (spaces, parenthesis, etc.) from that result:

```
{921163}
{814541}
{770593}
{772526}
{771130}
```

I've tried wrapping my regexp_matches term with a regexp_replace, and regular old replace, but I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is

```
[[:<:]][0-9]{6}[[:>:]]
```

which is word boundary.It will remove all the characters in the match itself.